# Variable to a Textbox vba

Tags: excel, vba, variables, textbox

I'm trying to add a range to a variable and then that variable will be the text that will be shown on the text box. And what I did so far is the code below:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim text1 As String
text1 = Sheet16.Range("C21:D40").Value
Sheet15.TextBox1.Value = text1
End Sub
```

and I got the error "Type mismatch" when I try to run it. Please any advise will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you don't specify `Dim text1 As String` but just do `Dim text1`?

Comment: A string can only be the value of one cell, not a range of cells

Comment: @Kyle makes an excellent point. What do you expect to see in the textbox? The concatenation of all the values in all the cells in the range?

Answer (score 0):

You can not assing a range to a string variable.

If you want to add up or to sum the range, you're code will look similar to this one:

```
Private Sub myAddingFunction()
    Dim text1As String
    text1= Application.Sum(Range("C21:D40"))
    Range("c1").Value = text1
End Sub
```

Where Range("c1") can be replaced for Sheet15.TextBox1.Value